# XPath in java won't accept variable in expression

Tags: java, xpath

Can someone be kind enough to explain me why
    xPath.evaluate("/MEMBER_LIST/MEMBER[1]/ADDRESS", nodeMemberList, XPathConstants.STRING)
Returns the value I'm looking for and why
    xPath.evaluate("/MEMBER_LIST/MEMBER[" + i + "]/ADDRESS", nodeMemberList, XPathConstants.STRING)
Returns an empty String?
I have to do these in a for loop so here "i" is an int representing the current entry.

Comment: Thank you guys. Thank God it was something as dumb as this. I'll keep my bitter comments for the few doc I found online stating 0 as the starting index with XPath

Answer (score 1):

Does your for loop start at 1?  The expression `/MEMBER_LIST/MEMBER[0]` isn't a valid XPath expression because XPath indexes start at 1.  Also, accessing an index which exceeds the total number of nodes is invalid.  For example, executing `/MEMBER_LIST/MEMBER[5]` when there are only 3 `MEMBER` elements.

You can also use the XPathConstants.NODESET constant.  This will return a list of all elements that match the given expression.  You can then iterate over the list.

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/MEMBER_LIST/MEMBER/ADDRESS", nodeMemberList, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i){
  Node node = nodeList.item(i);
  String address = node.getTextContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `i==0` the answer will be empty as XPath indexes start at 1.